# Height 0 doesnot hides DOM

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide a DOM by applying **height: 0px**. I hope because of the padding it doesn't hide the DOM completely. **I have also given border-box property**. I'm using height instead of display property in order to achieve smoothness(transition) while hiding. Please refer the code below

```js
var body = document.body;
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var close  = document.getElementById('close');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
close.onclick = closeBanner;
reset.onclick = resetHeight;

function closeBanner(){
 banner.style.height = 0;
}

function resetHeight(){
 banner.style.height = '40px';
}
```

```css
.banner{
  height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #2fc5c5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    border: 1px solid #10b5b4;

}
.close{
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" id="banner">
  <span> Content Goes here</span>
  <span class="close" id='close'>x</span>
</div>
 <button id="reset"> Reset Height</button>
```

Refer the fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/73naovLu/)

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter two separate issues with this method.

1. The reason why its still visible is, because it has a default
   padding, that would also be needed to be set to 0.
2. The container has a border, so even if you set the height to 0 and the padding to 0 you will still see something. So you would also have to remove the border on click :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the `padding` and `border`. You need to add some more `css` along with `height: 0;`

```
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
border: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the `height:0`, its better to fade it out by the following method:

```
$("#banner").fadeOut("slow");
```

The advantages of using `fadeOut()`:

1. You don't need to use additional css like `height:0` or `transition` etc.
2. It gives you a smooth transition.
3. It takes only one line to write this and reduces your code size.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var body = document.body;
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var close  = document.getElementById('close');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
close.onclick = closeBanner;
reset.onclick = resetHeight;

function closeBanner(){
 banner.style.height = 0;
  banner.style.padding = 0;
  banner.style.border = 0;
}

function resetHeight(){
 banner.style.height = '40px';
}
```

```css
.banner{
  height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #2fc5c5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    border: 1px solid #10b5b4;

}
.close{
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" id="banner">
  <span> Content Goes here</span>
  <span class="close" id='close'>x</span>
</div>
 <button id="reset"> Reset Height</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this helps you for solving your issue.

```js
var body = document.body;
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var close  = document.getElementById('close');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
close.onclick = closeBanner;
reset.onclick = resetHeight;

function closeBanner(){
 banner.style.height = 0;
  banner.style.padding = 0;
  banner.style.border = 0;
}

function resetHeight(){
 banner.style.height = '40px';
}
```

```css
.banner{
  height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #2fc5c5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    border: 1px solid #10b5b4;

}
.close{
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" id="banner">
  <span> Content Goes here</span>
  <span class="close" id='close'>x</span>
</div>
 <button id="reset"> Reset Height</button>
```